# Python 2: What is the most elegant/pythonic way of doing a enum with string interpretations?

Tags: python, enums

I want a enum with predefined single character constants (good for storing in database) and string interpretation. Here is what I am thinking of:

```
class Fruits(Enum):
    APPLE = 'A'
    PEAR = 'P'
    BANANA = 'B'
    def __unicode__(self):
        if self == APPLE: return "Crunchy Apple"
        if self == PEAR: return "Sweet Pear"
        if self == BANANA: return "Long Banana"
```

But

```
fruit = Fruits.APPLE
print fruit.__unicode__()
```

gives

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '__unicode__'
```

And besides there must be a more elegant way of doing it

How to do it better?

Comment: You appear to be using Python2. Can you confirm whether you are using Python2 or Python3? (You can examine `sys.version` to be sure.)

Comment: Where did `Fruits.TYPE_APPLE` come from? You only defined `Fruits.APPLE`. If you retyped the code in the question from memory, copy-paste it from a file you've actually run or an actual interactive session next time.

Comment: @Rob I am more interested in Python 2

Answer (score 5):

A couple observations:

- You shouldn't call `__dunder__` methods directly; instead use the matching command: `unicode` instead of `__unicode__`
- I am unable to duplicate your problem

Using the [stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) (3.4+) or the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) (Python 2.x) you will have to do it the hard way -- make your own base `Enum` class:

```
class EnumWithDescription(Enum):
    def __new__(cls, value, desc):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member.description = desc
        return member
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

class Fruits(EnumWithDescription):
    _order_ = 'APPLE PEAR BANANA'   # if using Python 2.x and order matters
    APPLE = 'A', 'Crunchy Apple'
    PEAR = 'P', 'Sweet Pear'
    BANANA = 'B', 'Long Banana'
```

and in use:

```
>>> fruit = Fruits.APPLE
>>> unicode(fruit)
u'Crunchy Apple'
```

---

If you can use the [`aenum library`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup> you will have an easier time of it:

```
from aenum import Enum

class Fruits(Enum, init='value description'):
    APPLE = 'A', 'Crunchy Apple'
    PEAR = 'P', 'Sweet Pear'
    BANANA = 'B', 'Long Banana'
    def describe(self):
        return self.description
```

and in use:

```
fruit = Fruits.APPLE
fruit.describe()
```

Note that since `unicode` is the default in Python 3 I changed the name to `describe`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score -1):

The [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) module has what you want.

```
from enum import Enum

class Fruits(Enum):
    apple = 'A'
    pear = 'P'
    banana = 'B'

fruit = Fruits.apple

print fruit.value
>> 'A'
```

Possibly even better is using integers

```
from enum import Enum

class Fruits(Enum):
    apple = 1
    pear = 2
    banana = 3

fruit = Fruits.apple

print fruit.value
>> 1
```

And recreate the object if you get it's value (from a database for instance) using:

```
fruit = Fruits(1)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Ah you're actually correct I think. But there's also fruit.name for the requested sting interpretation.